# Google Chart: Pass raw data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

I have a raw data table in the Google Chart example:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Time', 'Dollar', 'BTC'],
      ['-4h',  1000,      400], //this should go to -24h, so I would use a loop
      ['-3h',  1170,      460],
      ['-2h',  660,       1120],
      ['-1h',  1030,      540]
    ]);
```

Also, I got two arrays:

```
var dollar = [2000,3000,4000]; //They both will contain 24 values
var btc = [100,200,300]
```

How do I pass the arrays to the google function?

Comment: You want to make a dataTable with those 2 arrays or add the info from those 2 arrays to the dataTable you already have?

Comment: First one, creating the data table like this in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var data_arr=[['Time', 'Dollar', 'BTC']];
var hour=-24;
var dollar = [2000,3000,4000];
var btc = [100,200,300];

for(var index=0;index<dollar.length;index++){
    data_arr.push([hour+'h', dollar[index], btc[index]]);
    hour++;
}

var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data_arr);
```